# display: flex not working on safari after using transform scale X

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

I built a video player. It works fine on every browser but safari.

I add the transform scaleX to the volume container so when I hover on it, it will work as on youtube video volume

When not hover:

```
width: 0;
transform: scaleX(0);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
transform-origin: left;
transition: width 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: width 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
```

When hover:

```
width: 0.5rem;
transform: scaleX(1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
```

But when not hover, the display flex property of this volume container is not working by somehow. The animation and transform on hover still work normally:
[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RPnL.png)

I expect the result will be like this:
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTDsW.png)

Can anyone help me? I will be very grateful

Here's the link to test website: https://vinasports-web-player-test.vercel.app/

FIXED
by add an value to width:

```
width: 0.0001px
```

I don't know how but it worked. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question; please do not just send us to an external site to see the problematic code.